# How to set form key in form Ui Component

Tags: magento2

How i can add form-key input hidden into ui-form component manually? It is possible to get form-key data somewhere and put in input component. I have faced form-key missing problem in form when AJAX post data. Form-key missing and i need to add it inside form

```
<field name="form_key">
     <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
          <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
              <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
              <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">hidden</item>
              <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">form_key</item>
              <item name="value" xsi:type="string">getValueFormKeyAndPutInHere</item>
          </item>
     </argument>
</field>
```

Comment: Temporary comment here! Normal Form automatic populate form_key data when form is submitted. I have no idea why some cases ex: use form with modal and this value missing